# ASP.NET Timer CONTROL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, timer, webforms, controls

I have used ASP Timer control for my online exam project and hosted in IIS 7 Sever. The duration of exam time is stored in database and total duration of exam is 1:30 hour. Everything works perfectly for the first user who register and start exam. Problem start from second and next user. Suppose first user exam time remain is 1 hour at that time if any second user register and start test then first user timer value restart with second user and both user timer value start with initial value means 1:30 hour. similarly if third user registered and start  test then first and second user time get reset to third user time means initial value.

I have use Update panel used trigger for asp timer and also used !ispostback in page load section.

Any body can help what is the problem in timer control, or it is problem with IIS Server 7 ?

Comment: can you show your code? is your timer declared as static?